# .off and .on method to only clicked element in the set of class elements

Tags: jquery

Okay I have tried the possible ways to remove and add back the event handler but I did not get the solution. Well a class of anchor elements are dynamically generated and inserted into dom

```
<a class="linkpage">#1</a>
<a class="linkpage">#2</a>
<a class="linkpage">#3</a>
<a class="linkpage">#4</a>

function runme(){
    $(document).off("click","a.linkpage"); // turn off click 
    // some code
   $(document).on("click","a.linkpage",runme); // turn back on click
}

$(document).on("click","a.linkpage",runme);
```

The question is I want to remove click event only to the clicked link not to all the class elements 
and add back to it at the end of function.

Comment: This is an X/Y problem. Do not remove the event handler. Instead, make the handler do nothing while a previous handler is still being processed.

Comment: @KevinB if user clicked link 1 it may 2 to 3 minutes to complete its task so user may wish to click other link for another function to load. if i remove event or stop processing user may not be able to click the other links till the first link request finishes off

Comment: That doesn't change my suggestion. It is entirely possible to disable it for only one element. By removing the event you would be disabling it for all, since the event is only bound to a single element (the document).

Comment: @KevinB you mean currentelement.prop("disable") ? can you kindly provide me the answer your help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I mean, disable might work, but i would instead just return out of the function earlier if a flag on the element was true.

Comment: I downvoted because this is an X/Y problem. The problem you are trying to solve is one that isn't going to fix your actual problem. If you succeeded in removing the event, you would be removing it for ALL elements, not just the one that was clicked. The question needs to target the actual problem, not what you tried to solve the problem. The answer that i would write wouldn't really match what your question is asking, even if it does solve your real problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the event will not fix anything because it will remove the event from ALL of those anchor tags, not just the clicked one. You need to instead not process the event if an existing one is already being processed.

```
function runme () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.data("running")) {
        return; // exit early
    }
    $this.data("running", true);
    // some code
    $this.data("running", false); // this probably needs to go into the callback of whatever is taking 3 minutes to run.
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help but I have .data() in jquery takes a huge memory consumption is that true?

Comment: Not that i'm aware of. If you misuse it, it might, but i wouldn't consider this misuse. The data isn't actually being stored on the element itself, and it gets cleaned up whenever the element is removed by a jquery method.